# Highchart selection without zoom

Tags: highcharts

Is there any option to select coordinates(ie min and max) values by selection without zoom in Highchart.

Thanks.

Comment: Could you be a little more elaborate on the question? Also, a jsFiddle would be really appreciated. Also please let us know what have you tried, the highchart api reference is very helpful @ http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this out: http://jsfiddle.net/8LBFp/

Comment: +1 vote up. and want to know how I remain selected rectangle area  as it is, once I select range.  [see here](http://prntscr.com/3cbal8)

Comment: I know you have already gave answer on http://stackoverflow.com/a/12602755/2419644 but I have date on x-axis and that's why I stuck at point. Please help me here.